# How to write the CASE WHEN query in the right way for a specific logic

Tags: sql, case-when

I have a query that is giving me an error:

```
select
CardType,
CASE 
WHEN ISNUMERIC(m.CardType) = 1
THEN 
CASE 
    WHEN m.CardType = '30' THEN m.NonBankCard*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD) 
    WHEN m.CardType <> '30' AND m.CardType < '40' AND left(m.CardType,1) = '3' or m.CardType = '03' THEN m.PinDebit*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD) 
    WHEN m.CardType > '39' AND m.CardType < '60' AND m.CardType <> '5H' and (left(m.CardType,1) = '4' or left(m.CardType,1) = '5') THEN ((m.Auth+m.Cap+m.Settle)/3.0000)*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD)
    WHEN m.CardType = '5H' THEN ((m.Auth+m.Cap+m.Settle)/3.0000)*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD)
ELSE m.PIExpMTD END [PerItemCost]

from [dbo].[Monetary_CADetailed]
```

What I need is to execute CASE logic for each card types if CardType is numeric, otherwise do

```
ELSE m.PIExpMTD
```

What is the correct way to write that?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  And be explicit on what error you are getting.

Comment: with sqlserver u are isnumeric function : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnumeric.asp

Comment: Note that `ISNUMERIC('5H')` produces `0`, and as written the `CASE ... WHEN m.CardType = '5H' THEN ......` will never be hit.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have nested `CASE` statements, you'll need a second `END`.

```
select
CardType,
CASE 
WHEN ISNUMERIC(m.CardType) = 1
THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN m.CardType = '30' THEN m.NonBankCard*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD) 
        WHEN m.CardType <> '30' AND m.CardType < '40' AND left(m.CardType,1) = '3' or m.CardType = '03' THEN m.PinDebit*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD) 
        WHEN m.CardType > '39' AND m.CardType < '60' AND m.CardType <> '5H' and (left(m.CardType,1) = '4' or left(m.CardType,1) = '5') THEN ((m.Auth+m.Cap+m.Settle)/3.0000)*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD)
        WHEN m.CardType = '5H' THEN ((m.Auth+m.Cap+m.Settle)/3.0000)*(m.DebitItemsMTD+m.CreditItemsMTD)
    END
ELSE m.PIExpMTD 
END [PerItemCost]

from [dbo].[Monetary_CADetailed]
```